# How do I remove python3.7 from ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (python3.8 is bundled with distro itself)?

Tags: package-management, python, uninstall, python3

**TL;DR**

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ships with python3.8 as the default and almost half of its core components depend on it. I installed python3.7 and built it from source which installed it as python3. Now running `python3` results in python3.7. running `python3.8` results in python3.8. running `python3.7` results in python3.7. (Running in gnome-terminal, results as in which interpreter get called). Now I want to remove python3.7 without affecting python3.8 and other components so that `python3` would point to python3.8 which would be the only interpreter installed. How do I go about this?

**To exlplain a few things which complicate the issue for me**

Well first up I ran `sudo apt remove python3`. Now I knew that python3.8 is the base of a few core components (including terminal, software center, update utility and a lot more). But as `python3` was referring to python3.7 in the terminal, I decided to give that a go thinking it would remove 3.7, not 3.8. And as I had expected, it screwed up the OS. gnome-terminal and a few other things were gone, and it was very  silly of me not to read the list of packages it asked `y/n` for.

I tried looking on is there a way to do a factory reset but that was not possible. The shortcuts keys for bringing up a terminal shell were not working for me else I could've just done `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. After no luck from within ubuntu, I restarted and booted to windows 10. and then when I tried to boot back into ubuntu, it won't load. and it looked like the only way to fix that would've been a re-install which I didn't want to do 'cause I had lot of stuff in there.

I fixed that by selecting option `advanced options for ubuntu` in the grub menu, then doing a few recovery things (I basically went with any option that looked related to the issue as I was desperate). After a few selections I had a shell window where I logged in to my ubuntu account, and run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` which installed all the missing packages. And I was able to boot into ubuntu later on.

And now I want to remove python3.7 in the *safe way* so that I don't loose anything. I also just want to work with python3.8 which is the default install so `python3` should point to python3.8 which would be the only interpreter installed in the system.

If you need any additional info from me, please let me know.

Thank You For Any Help or Suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave python 3.7 installed along side 3.8 without a problem. Many developers have multiple versions installed. Trying to manually remove all of the python 3.7 parts manually, since you compiled from source, may cause more issues so the best solution is to set the default python version system wide.

First, list all the versions you have installed.
`ls /usr/bin/python*`

Then follow the `Change python version system-wide` section in [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux) guide, using the info you gathered from the `ls` command, to make python3.8 the default system wide.

Comment: is that a possibility to somehow `remove` the directory that contains py3.7, AFTER setting default system wide `python3` -> `python3.8` ? just curious else I'm good with just setting system wide ref too..

Comment: Once you set the system wide default your system will use that. Could you remove the py 3.7 dir? Possibly. I guess I'm asking why? Why does it need removing? You could rename the directory, something like `mv python3.7 python3.7-bak` and if anything were to break you could simply rename it back.

Comment: alright. thanks for the help :)